# Exact four-sample proportion test for difference-in-differences analysis?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, binary-data, proportion

Assume I have a binomial variable.

I can test whether the proportion is different from zero, using an exact test.

I can test whether the proportions in two samples are different, using an exact test

How can I test whether the difference-in-differences of proportions is different (using four samples), using an exact test? Or at least not relying on Normal asymptotic inference.

I know I can use a regression. But then my inference would rely on Normal asymptotic, which is clearly misspecified. I also do not want to make functional form assumptions on the error terms which a Logit/Probit regression would do.

Formulated using `R`:

```r
N <- 20
set.seed(42)
a <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.2)
b <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.4)
c <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.4)
d <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.7)

# Exact test against null hypothesis that a proportion is different from 0
binom.test(sum(a), N, 0)
#> 
#>  Exact binomial test
#> 
#> data:  sum(a) and N
#> number of successes = 6, number of trials = 20, p-value < 2.2e-16
#> alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.1189316 0.5427892
#> sample estimates:
#> probability of success 
#>                    0.3

# Exact test against null hypothesis that two proportions are equal
prop.test(c(sum(a), sum(b)), c(N, N))
#> 
#>  2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity
#>  correction
#> 
#> data:  c(sum(a), sum(b)) out of c(N, N)
#> X-squared = 1.6368, df = 1, p-value = 0.2008
#> alternative hypothesis: two.sided
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -0.59643443  0.09643443
#> sample estimates:
#> prop 1 prop 2 
#>   0.30   0.55

# Exact test against null hypothesis that difference in proportions is equal (b - a = c - d)
# ???
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Does difference in difference make sense applied directly to proportions?   e.g. Imagine (using the terminology [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences#General_definition)) you have a treatment that you believe increases the response. Your control group goes from p=0.7 to 0.9 and the treatment group starts from 0.85. What happens under H0?  Under H1?  ... I'd have thought you could maybe apply a difference-in-difference type idea to the linear predictor in a logistic regression or a probit regression but it doesn't make sense to me on the scale of p itself.

Comment: (1) It'd be better to describe the tests you're referencing than rely on R code. For a start, the 2nd one is not an exact test. (2) Are you sure you want to test homogeneity of differences in proportions rather than of relative risk or of odds ratios?

Comment: adding to Scortchi answer. The exact test in this case would be Barnard's test. You used asymptotic Person's chi-squared.

Comment: @Wassermann: The exact unconditional test; the exact conditional test being of course Fisher's Exact Test.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica: exactly!